# UIActivityindicatorView in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I am downloading videos and playing  with MPMoviePlayercontroller, i want to display uiactivityindicatorview in mpmovieplayercontroller while video is being downloaded as in YouTube app.
How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
activityIndicator.center = myMPMoviePlayercontroller.center;
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[myMPMoviePlayercontroller.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
myMPMoviePlayercontroller addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

See the [UIActivityIndicatorView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html) for more info.

Comment: I tried ur code but when video starts to play activityindicator must hide but still it is running.

Comment: Use `[activityIndicator stopAnimating];` right before you play the video or in a delegate method that gets called when the video starts.  This will hide the `activityIndicator`.

Comment: Very cool, glad it worked!  Please also accept the answer if you feel it resolved the issue (the check-box under the number to the left of the answer).

Comment: Ok chown now i have click on check-box:-) Thanks again.